# .click() doesnt work in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, click

This little peace of code works in Firefox, but not Safari:

```
$('.pinterest-button').click(function() {
    $('.pinterest-button').hide();
    $('#pin1 a img').click();
    setTimeout("$('.pinterest-button').show();", 1000);
});
```

If the pinterest button is clicked, it should create a click-event for that picture:

```
<div id="pin1" class="gallery span24 offset6">
   <a class="span24" alt="" title="bild" href="javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());">
      <img class="gallery-img" src="http://www.goldentree.de/wordpress/assets/bild.jpg">
   </a>
</div>
```

If I click the button in Safari, it is getting hidden and the page scrolls to top, so the click itself works, but I think the $('#pin1 a img').click(); that should trigger the code in the images href doesnt work. I found some other people having the same problem, but none of their solutions work for me, so I'm not completely sure if its really the click() that does not work. Im also not sure, what makes my browser scroll to top, because I thought that is made by the pinterest overlay-thing. Oh and yes: Directly clicking on the picture works.

Comment: Works for me on Chrome and Safari (Mac)

Comment: Try  `$('#pin1 a').click()`

Comment: I'm using Safari for Windows. And unfortunately $('#pin1 a') doesnt work either.

Comment: i have the exact same problem, have you found a fix for it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. People said, it works in normal not-windows Safari, but I never tested it. If you can find a solution that works cross-browser, please post it here.

Answer (score 2):

This problem might be caused by two things

**1. The DOM is not ready yet when you attached the listener**

**2. Your HTML code is added dynamically**

The solution for the **first case** is to put your code under the ready block

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pinterest-button').click(function() {
        $('.pinterest-button').hide();
        $('#pin1 a img').click();
        setTimeout("$('.pinterest-button').show();", 1000);
    });
});
```

The solution for the **2nd case** is to make the listener live for any changes

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.pinterest-button').on('click',function() {
            $('.pinterest-button').hide();
            $('#pin1 a img').click();
            setTimeout("$('.pinterest-button').show();", 1000);
        });
    });
```

**and add the on click to your image listener** if needed

I hope this can help

Comment: `.on("click",...)` is the perfered way going forward.

Comment: The function is already called from $documnt).ready. Also the second sollution doesnt work. And as I said. The pinterest button is getting hidden and reappears in Safari, so the problem is not, that my function isnt called. It is probably that $('#pin1 a img').click() doesnt work.

Comment: Is there any function for the img .click ?

Comment: It's ok, I mean when I click on the img what happens this line of code what it does  $('#pin1 a img').click();

Comment: The javascript code in the href attribute calls the pinterest overlay, in which you can select an image to share. The purpose of the .click() is to call that code from a pinterest button at the top of the post.

Comment: Then you need to remove the img $('#pin1 a').click();

Answer (score 1):

I think this is most like an issue related to Safari itself:

https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/4565